# How to reduce PHP Execution Time and how to set ini_set() in PHP?

Tags: php, csv, memory-management

I have a problem in Php file Execution Time, first I tell what I did in PHP file.. I need to Generate CSV file so I wrote Query to fetch data from DB. and My query return 1 million record and I have use PHP fwrite() to write data into CSV file. but my script Taken `76.481406211853` sec to generate one csv file ehich contains 1 million of data. How to reduce this execution time? Sometime I got fatal error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1048576 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 793601 bytes)

so, how to manage memory?

PHP code here:

```
<?php   
// start script
$time_start = microtime(true);
echo_memory_usage();

//My logic here

// End of Script
echo 'Total execution time in seconds: ' . (microtime(true) - $time_start);
echo_memory_usage();

function echo_memory_usage() { 
    $mem_usage = memory_get_usage(true); 

    if ($mem_usage < 1024) 
        echo $mem_usage." bytes"; 
    elseif ($mem_usage < 1048576) 
        echo round($mem_usage/1024,2)." kilobytes"; 
    else 
        echo round($mem_usage/1048576,2)." megabytes"; 

    echo "<br/>"; 
}
?>
```

My result is

```
512 kilobytes //Script start
1006.25 megabytes // script End 
Total execution time in seconds: 76.481406211853
```

And successfully write CSV file with 1 million record.. but execution time too long and sometime throws Fatal Error. And also how to set ini_set()? Because I have to set `ini_set('memory_limit', '1023M');`

The reason of I set 1023, after script run memory usage is 1006.25, so I have to set 1023M? Is it correct way?

Comment: To clarify, does 10 laks mean 1 million?

Comment: the code you've shown doesn't show what you're doing at all, it just shows '//My logic here'. Best way to fix this is to query the DB & then loop through the resultset 1 row at a time & write the entries to the file, but without seeing any relevant code, it's hard to suggest how to improve it

Comment: Also, without going to wikipedia, most people here won't know what a lak is - suggest using English to describe your problem to a wider audience

Comment: yes 1 Million @Steve

Answer (score 1):

Execution time depends on the external connections, db connections and loops of same script. Try to do one step per time: 
1. let the script just connect  to db doing nothing
2. let the script read the data
3. let the script prepare the data for saving

Write down the execution time for every case to check where the fault is.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
You can change `memory_limit` in your php.ini file.

**Option 2:**
Maybe you are using heavy objects or slow connections.
If you want to improve your code you can test it here:

```php
// Code 1
$start = microtime(true);

/* Here the code 1 */

$timeTotal1 = microtime(true) - $start;
echo 'Code 1: '. $timeTotal1 .'<br>';


// Code 2
$start = microtime(true);

/* Here the code 2 */

$timeTotal2 = microtime(true) - $start;
echo 'Code 2: '. $timeTotal2 .'<br>';

// Winner
echo '<b>Winner:</b> '. ( $timeTotal1 > $timeTotal2 ? 'Code 2' : 'Code 1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would do this via the php.ini of your webserver, but you can also do it like this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

Values are specified like 16,32,64 always ending with the "M" for megabytes.

Or just remove the limit:

```
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
```

Comment: to the OP - be aware that removing the limit is usually a bad idea, especially if the script is already using 1GB of memory - this is indicative of bad coding/logic & you should focus on fixing this rather than giving your script unlimited resources